# UIScrollView with AutoLayouts programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a `UIScrollView` which i want to scroll vertically. I am creating `UIScrollView` programmatically and facing problems with Auto layouts.

I have added single child into a `UIScrollView` and rest of the controls have been added on that child view.

Following Code will create `UIScrollView` and `contentView` of Scroll View

```
lazy var scrollView : UIScrollView = {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
   // scrollView.backgroundColor = .red
    return scrollView
}()

let contentView: UIView = {
    let contentV = UIView()
    contentV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentV.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    return contentV
}()
```

Following Code will add `UIScrollView` inside main `view` and `contentView` inside `UIScrollView`

```
view.addSubview(scrollView)

    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
```

//Content View

```
scrollView.addSubview(contentView)

    contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true


    contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

    contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

after doing this I am trying to add other controls on the `contentView` But my `view` is not showing properly, See the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiBEK.png) I have googled many tutorials for adding scroll view programmatically but unable to do it so.

Comment: I suppose that it is because you have missed height constraint for contentView. In your example contentView has zero height.

Comment: after watching some more tutorials found the solution had to add height constraints also @MarkKryzhanouski you are right. Content View must have height and width of main View `contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true and contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true`